# Avoiding going through npm when an internal developed package changes

Tags: javascript, npm

I divided my project into NPM packages. So I developed a few packages and use NPM when one package or another changes.

This is my package dependency tree:

```
----- A
      |----  B
      |
      |      |----  C
```

Every time I change package C I build, deploy, reload, repeat:

```
gulp deploy C
npm publish
cd ../projectB (or J for autojump)
yarn add C@^0.1.0
gulp deploy B
npm publish
j projectA
yarn add B^0.1.13
npm start
```

Needless to say this takes time for every little change. Is there a good way to work with npm packages locally until I deploy them?

Comment: Not entirely sure about what you're asking, but maybe what you need is npm link https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link